# Pushing to "qa" branch did not trigger "qa" build, instead it triggers "dev" build

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have this ci.yml workflow.

```
jobs:
  dev_build:
    if: ${{ !(contains(github.base_ref, 'master') || contains(github.base_ref, 'main') || contains(github.head_ref, 'master') || contains(github.head_ref, 'main') || contains(github.base_ref, 'qa') || contains(github.head_ref, 'qa')) }}

       .
       .
       .

   qa_build:
    if: ${{ contains(github.base_ref, 'qa') || contains(github.head_ref, 'qa') }}
       .
       .
       .
```

But everytime I make a push to the "qa" branch, it triggers the "dev_build" instead of the "qa_build". Is there something wrong with my condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accodringly to [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)

> The base_ref or target branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either pull_request or pull_request_target.

and

> The head_ref or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either pull_request or pull_request_target.

So simple push to qa branch will not work here as because this values are populated on pull_request and pull_request_target events.

And first job is triggered because this part `!(contains(github.base_ref, 'master')`

You also have onlu CI trigger and not PR triggers. Look at this difference:

Ci triggers:

[image]

with PR triggers:

[image]

I tested this with following:

```yaml
name: so-034-conditions

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, main, qa ]
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  dev_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ !(contains(github.base_ref, 'master') || contains(github.base_ref, 'main') || contains(github.head_ref, 'master') || contains(github.head_ref, 'main') || contains(github.base_ref, 'qa') || contains(github.head_ref, 'qa')) }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
      - name: Test1
        id: test1
        run: |
          
          echo "Deploying $GITHUB_REF"
          echo "Deploying ${{ github.event_name }}"
  qa_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ contains(github.base_ref, 'qa') || contains(github.head_ref, 'qa') }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout this repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
      - name: Test1
        id: test1
        run: |
          echo "${{ github.base_ref }}"
          echo "Deploying ${{ github.event_name }}"
```

Comment: hi I have this in my ci.yml file. it seems that I also have the PR trigger
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master,develop,qa ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master,develop,qa ]

Comment: Do you have PR oppened? If not you will not get pull_request event. Only then your pipeline will work as you expect. You need to have PR opened and then make a push to a branch. Please check this.